# Proof on Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be element of Endomorphism of V (V is a finite dimensional vector space over F) such that A is onto. 
Assume that there exist a function 
B: V $\to$ V such that BA = I. Prove that AB = I

- Can you give me a hint on how to prove this problem? Thanks.

Here is working solution. Since A is onto, there exist x in V such that A(x) = v.

We need to show that BA = I.

(BA)(x) = B(A(x)) = B(v) then I don't know what's next

Comment: Is $V$ a vector space? Finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, it is a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: There is no need for $V$ being a vector space. This is valid for surjective functions $f: X \to Y$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216569/assuming-ab-i-prove-ba-i, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is onto, right? And $BA = 1$ implies $A$ is one-to-one, so $A$ is an automorphism. Multiplying by its inverse from the right gives $B = A^{-1}$, which implies $AB = 1$. No linearity was needed.

This is a simple statement of category theory: Every epi section is an iso and its retraction is its inverse. If $rs = 1$ and $\forall x, y :\ xs = ys \Rightarrow x=y$, then $srs = s$, so $sr = 1$ and $r$ and $s$ are inverse.