# Linear Algebra - Prove $AB=BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be any $n \times n$ defined over the real numbers.

Assume that $A^2+AB+2I=0$.

- Prove $AB=BA$

**My solution (Not full)**

I didn't managed to get so far.

$A(A+B)=-2I$

$-\frac{1}{2}(A(A+B)=I$

Therefore $A$ reversible and $A+B$ reversible.

I don't know how to get on from this point, What could I conclude about $A^2+AB+2I=0?$

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/153143.

Comment: @polmath Interesting link !

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$
A(A+B)=A^2+AB=-2I
$$
we have that
$$
A^{-1}=-\frac12(A+B)
$$
then multiplying by $-2A$ on the right and adding $2I$ gives
$$
A^2+BA+2I=0=A^2+AB+2I
$$
Cancelling common terms yields
$$
BA=AB
$$

---

**Another Approach**

Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/216659) (involving more work than the previous answer), which says that
$$
AB=I\implies BA=I
$$
we get
$$
-\frac12A(A+B)=I\implies-\frac12(A+B)A=I
$$
Cancelling common terms gives $AB=BA$.

Comment: What do you mean subtracting the original equation? $A^2+BA+2I=0$ is the original equation.

Comment: Yes, subtract $A^2+AB+2I=0$ from $A^2+BA+2I=0$ gives $BA-AB=0$ which is the same as $BA=AB$. I've modified the last line in case that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

If $-\frac{1}{2}A(A+B)=I$, then $(A+B)\cdot(-\frac{1}{2}A)$ is also $I$, since $-\frac{1}{2}A$ and $A+B$ are each other inverses. Then $A^2+AB=A^2+BA$, and so $AB=BA$.

Comment: Can you explain why since $-\frac{1}{2}A$ and $A+B$ inverses $A^2+AB=A^2+BA?$

Comment: Since $-\frac{1}{2}A$ and $A+B$ are each other inverses, you have $-\frac{1}{2}A\cdot (A+B)=(A+B)\cdot (-\frac{1}{2}A)$ (and both equal $I$). Now multiply both sides by $-2$. Get $A(A+B)=(A+B)A$, and then open the brackets.